# Hiding defined names and values in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to hide defined names and their values in Excel, I succeeded in hiding the names but the values are still appearing, here is the VBA code.

```
Sub HideNames()
Dim xName As Name
For Each xName In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Names
    xName.Visible = False
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: How do you mean?  Hide them on the sheet?

Comment: Appearing where?

Comment: You probably want to delete them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, simply you need to protect the sheet.